# Is there a python implementation of the MCR-ALS algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, least-squares

Multivariate Curve Resolution-Alternating Least Squares (MCR-ALS) is a popular chemometric method used for the resolution of multiple component responses in unknown unresolved mixtures. I would like to use this method in a python program. But I could not find this in the scikit-learn package. Is there any equivalent in this package? or where can I find an implementation of this method in python? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would using [`RPy`](http://rpy.sourceforge.net) to wrap [an R implementation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ALS/index.html) be acceptable?

Comment: yes this is one option. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (mostly from Google/PyPI/AS/mailing-list searches), there is no pure-Python implementation, and no external implementation with Python bindings.

However, you can always write your own bindings to an external implementation.

[CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) has an R implementation called [ALS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ALS/index.html) that seems like it might fit the bill. You can use [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net) to bind to R code from Python. I'd try this first.

I also found some code packaged as a DLL (presumably with C headers), a partial sample implementation written in C, and various other similar things. I didn't find anything that I could just build and use, but maybe you can. There are of course a variety of ways to bind to native code from Python—[ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), [Cython](http://www.cython.org), etc. (If the native code is written in Fortran, use [F2py](http://www.scipy.org/F2py) instead of writing everything from scratch.)

There's also a [MATLAB](http://www.ub.edu/mcr/web_mcr/mcrals.html) implementation out there—in fact, most search links seem to go there. You can't directly bind to MATLAB code, but you can drive MATLAB's scripting engine, e.g., with [PyMat](http://pymat.sourceforge.net), which should work.

There were also some dead links to what looks like a Java implementation. If you can use Jython instead of CPython, that's easy to interface with. (And likewise for .NET and IronPython.)

Comment: Have you found a pure python application during the last years? I have had a look but I can not find one yet.

Comment: @StijnVanDaele I'm trying to transcode from the R package source into Python currently. If you found one or coded one yourself and are willing to share, I'd be grateful

Comment: I used the github package: spectrochempy by Arnaud Travert. Have a look in the analysis file.